# Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object library

Tags: dao

I have an application in VB6 that uses `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object library`.

It is already included in MS Office 2000 and above installation.

Is Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object library available in Windows XP/Vista/7 default installation, so that those who do not have MS Office installed can run this application.

Its default location is `program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll`

Comment: Just for reference, it appears that some version of Office stopped including this DLL or possibly moved it somewhere else. We had problems with our application when running on machines that only had office 2013 installed.